# Trying to EXTRACT FROM A TEXT FILE SPECIFIC LINES OF DATA AND CREATE A NEW OUTPUT TEXT FILE

Tags: error-handling

I keep getting this **error** with my code;

```
fout.write(line)  #writing in the data
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

**CODE**

```
with open("READ.txt") as fin:  #opening the input files (text file)
  lines = fin.readlines() #reading lines by line
with open("out.txt", "w") as fout: #opening the output files
                 for line in lines[20:62289]:  #selecting just the lines you need
                     fout.write(line)  #writing in the data
                     fout.close()  #ensure you close to save the file and it data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `fout.close()`. You're running it every iteration through the `for` loop, causing fout to be closed after writing the first line. Since you're using `with ... as fout` you don't actually need `fout.close()` at all. Just remove that line and you should be good.